# How can I remove leading "the"s during a Java sort?

Tags: java, android

I have an Android `ListView` I would like to sort. Currently I am using `Collections.sort` which alphabetizes just fine.

However, I would like to take one step further and move the leading "the".  Is there a built in Java or Android method that can handle this?

If not, what is the code I would need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Collections.sort()` with a custom `Comparator<String>` that strips out leading `"The"`s before comparing strings.

```
List<String> foo = /* init */;

Comparator<String> ignoreLeadingThe = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override public int compare(String a, String b) {
        // TODO check for nulls?

        // (?i) makes the match case-insensitive
        a = a.replaceAll("(?i)^the\\s+", "");
        b = b.replaceAll("(?i)^the\\s+", "");

        // TODO use compareToIgnoreCase() instead?
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
};

Collections.sort(foo, ignoreLeadingThe);
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/6hogi

Comment: I'd probably also down-case, but I guess that depends on the usecase.

Comment: Thanks I 'll check that out and be back in a few to mark correct!

Comment: @KickingLettuce I haven't actually tested this, let me know if you run into any issues, or if the code doesn't compile.

Comment: You also might want to use compareToIgnoreCase instead of comapreTo. In most cases, when sorting alphabetically, you don't want to have upper case first and then lower case

Comment: I went ahead and marked correct but will not be able to test for several more hours.  Will let you know!  Thanks for your simple answer and code sample.

Comment: @KickingLettuce I've added a demo and made the code actually compile. I also tweaked the regexp a bit, so you can see this work right in your browser.